# How do you get the args used in a discord.py command?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a custom help command for my bot in discord.py, and I want to have the args listed in a command  example like the default one has, like this: `c!ping [datetime=True]`. Is there any way to do this? Here is my current command:

```py
from typing import Optional

from discord.ext import commands
import discord

from bot.utilities import get_yaml_val

colors = get_yaml_val("config.yml", "colors")["colors"]

class Help(commands.Cog):
    """Cog for the help command."""
    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def help(self, ctx: commands.Context, command: Optional[str] = None):
        """This help command."""
        if not command:
            embed = discord.Embed(
                title="Catbot Help",
                description="A detailed list of all commands",
                color=colors["light_blue"]
            )
            for key, value in self.bot.docs.items():
                embed.add_field(
                    name=key, 
                    value=value
                )
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        else:
            command = command.lower()
            command_data = self.bot.docs.get(command)
            if command_data is None:
                await ctx.send(f"`{command}` is an invalid command!")
                return
            embed = discord.Embed(
                title="Catbot help",
                description="Test",
                color=colors["light_blue"]
            )
            embed.add_field(name=command, value=command_data)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)



def setup(bot: commands.Bot):
    """Loads cog."""
    bot.add_cog(Help(bot))
    docs = {"help": Help.help.help}
    bot.docs.update(docs)
    print(Help.help.args())
```

I do the docs update for every cog.

Comment: Please make this a [mcve]. Are you using the commands extension or just vanilla d.py?

Comment: commands extension

Comment: @SuperStormer MRE added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

discord.py has excellent help command support. I suggest you look at [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=helpcommand#discord.ext.commands.HelpCommand) before making your own help command.

```py
# you are using self.bot.docs to get command, I assume thats your own implementation.
command = self.bot.get_command(command)
if command is None:
   print('invalid command')
else:
  command_string = f" {command.qualified_name} {command.signature}"
```

`command.qualified_name` returns the entire command (with parent command if any)
`command.signature` returns the argument, its type and default if any.

### References:

- [`get_command`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=get_command#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_command)
- [`command.qualified_name`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=qualified_name#discord.ext.commands.Command.qualified_name)
- [`command.signature`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=command%20signature#discord.ext.commands.Command.signature)

Note:
I don't think there are many useful tutorials available on `HelpCommand`, if you want to implement it, you can take a look at how these public bots implement it.

[RoboDanny](https://github.com/Rapptz/RoboDanny/blob/rewrite/cogs/meta.py)--> very complex help command

[TechWithTim](https://github.com/SylteA/Discord-Bot/blob/master/cogs/_help.py)

Comment: Thank you! That seems like it should work